# Develop Visual Web Part Without Installing Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

I want to know if it is possible to develop web parts without installing sharepoint?

I choose Visual Web Part then I get sharepoint not installed error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't develop it without SharePoint on same machine.

Comment: Do you know a way to develop visual web part by installing a sharepoint which has little requirements? Because sharepoint needs lots of requirements like sql server windows server and sharepoint

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "Yes", you can. But if you do that then you loose all features of Visual Studio for development for SharePoint. You will need to create proper visual web part project artifact structure manually which could be tricky. Also you will have to create wsp package manually or using tools like [wsp builder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/). Then you can copy this wsp package to sharepoint server and deploy it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I guess WSP builder works with sharepoint 2010. I have sharepoint 2013 / online

Comment: It is just an example. You can always create wsp files manually. They are simple cab files.

Comment: Apart from your solution, Do you know a way to develop visual web part by installing a sharepoint which has little requirements? Because sharepoint needs lots of requirements like sql server windows server and sharepoint

Comment: Unfortunately no. Currently i'm also struggling from SharePoint been to greedy. SharePoint on my dev environment takes almost 8 gb of memory. If i enable search it takes 12 gb and more.

Comment: Did you install windows server and sql server too? Are these requirements/softwares are musts to install sharepoint? Because I want to install as little as software to develop visual web part.

Comment: You can install SharePoint foundation on single server. In this case SharePoint include SQL server express so you do not need to install it separately. Yes, I installed Windows Server 2012.